# CSV overwrites username and password in Python

Tags: python, csv, authentication, overwrite

I've been coding for a project and is to make a login/ sign in with python and by using  csv file. The problem is that when it makes a user and password in the csv file it overwrites the previous one meaning their can only be one user and password.

My code right now looks like this...

```
import time
def sign_menu():
  time.sleep(2)
  print()
  print('          Create a username and')
  print( '                password')
  NewUser = input('          Username: ')
  NewpWord = input('          Password: ')
  with open('UserPassword.csv', 'w') as outfile:
     outfile.write("username," + NewUser)
     outfile.write("password," + NewpWord)
```

Also my csv file looks like this...

> username,password,

if you could improve the code it would be appreciated and if you could explain on how to make it not overwrite that would also be helpful.
Thank you.

Comment: use `a` --> `with open('UserPassword.csv', 'a') as outfile:`

Comment: To be honest. I would simply go with an `sqlite` database. Interfacing is dead simple and The SQL part is very very compact here. If you want to stick to the filebased solution, read all users from the file BEFORE any change, make your change in memory and rewrite the file. Maybe make a backup in Between. This way you don't need to worry in case of removed users.

Comment: Cool thanks for your help.

Comment: Mark one of the answer as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use in your code the following line with `'w'`, which means (over)**writing** in the file:

```
open('UserPassword.csv', 'w')
```

Instead you should use `'a'`, which means **appending** to the file, as follows:

```
open('UserPassword.csv', 'a')
```

Comment: Cool. That makes sense. Cheers for your help

Comment: You're welcome. As mrangry777 wrote, please mark one of the answer as correct.